# Submitting Chinese Characters to a form displays incorrectly - UTF8 encoding used throughout 

Tags: php, cakephp, encoding, utf-8, cjk

I'm using CakePHP.
I have:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` is set in my template.

`Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');` is set.

My database is using `utf-8` encoding, (in `database.php - (encoding=>'utf8')` and if I manually enter Chinese characters they are stored correctly; and I can output them with no problems.

This screenshot shows the output:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P04iz.jpg]

Number 1 is the result when I manually paste Chinese characters in to my MYSQL database (using `utf8_unicode_ci`).

4 and 5 is what happens when I post Chinese characters from my form - unintelligible gibberish.

The form encoding is:

`<form action="/controller/add" accept-charset="utf-8" id="ControllerAddForm" method="post">`

so it should be accepting `utf-8` characters. I can type them in; they display okay in the text box, but whatever I submit becomes horribly mangled.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does firebug in firefox say if you check the header that is passed to the user (does it say html/text encoding utf8?) - also: are your files saves as utf8 without bom?

Comment: Just a couple thoughts - is the POSTed form data OK before being inserted into the db?  If so, is the data mangled when doing a find() via Cake as well as a manual SELECT query from the mysql prompt?  Also, setting the UTF8 in database.php doesn't necessarily mean your database is UTF8 - run a SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name to check the default charset.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also set the database connection to UTF-8 in `database.php`?

For MySQL, that would be:

```
'encoding' => 'utf8' // no hyphen
```

Comment: thanks; I have this in place already, will amend to make that clearer. have double checked; and the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

like mark and Brian said, check the **Accept-Encoding** parameter in your POST header and your database **character set**.

Answer (score 0):

Probably those are not UTF-8 compatible characters...

http://www.126.com/ uses charset=gb2312

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_2312